# absolute imports not working properly in project

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I am very confused as to why my absolute imports are not working. I have googled this and I tried implementing all possible solutions without success. I don't want to append anything to sys.path, I am following the exact instructions of PEP8 and I'd like to make it work without any hacks/shortcuts - unless a hack is the only way.

Every basic tutorial says to do it like this, but for some reason it just doesn't work for me.
My project structure is the following, using Python 3.7.6

```
module\
-------__init__.py
-------\folder_1
----------------__init__.py
----------------file1.py
-------\folder_2
----------------__init__.py
----------------file2.py
```

in module\folder_1\file1.py I do:

```
from module.folder_2 import file_2
```

FYI I run it through the terminal 'python file1.py', but I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module'
```

**Edit:**
I figured out the problem. I was running 'python file1.py', but when you do that it runs it as a script, when in fact it's a module. How you run the file makes a difference on the result.
I have tested the module not by running file1.py, but by actually using the module somewhere through 'import module' and all was fine.